# Issues printing embedded PDF

Tags: pdf, embed

I have embedded a pdf object in a webpage. When I print this page, the embedded object does not show in the printout. The only way to print the pdf is to use the print function of the plugin, however I need to add some headers to the pdf document that is on the top of the web page. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Already tried [Pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to modify the PDF file?